# javascript d3 - Adding Search option in Sunburst

Tags: javascript, html, search, d3.js

Can anyone please tell me how we can add a search functionality to the sunburst?

http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/477c1bfb081b783f80ad

I am trying to include a text input which highlights the arcs whose name property match with the input given.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a search text and button.
So now on click iterate through all the paths and set its opacity as 0.1.
While that which matches make its opacity 1.

Something like this:

```
d3.select("body").append("input").attr("id", "searchid");
d3.select("body").append("button")
    .attr("type", "button")
    .text("search")
    .on('click', function () {
    svg.selectAll("path")[0].forEach(function (d) {
        d3.select(d).style("opacity", 1); //making all paths to opacity 1
        if (d3.select(d).data()[0].name == document.getElementById("searchid").value) {
            d3.select(d).style("opacity", 1);//making matching path's to opacity 1

        } else {
            d3.select(d).style("opacity", 0.1);//making matching path's to opacity 0.1
        }
    })

});
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/4435yd26/5/).

In the example, search for name in the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. Works perfectly even when duplicates present in the arcs.